# skpsmtpmessage in different thread

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, email

I have just successfully implemented skpsmtpmessage into my iPhone app. This works fine, but it runs on the main thread, causing the UI to lock up until the operation is complete. Therefore I have tried moving it to a second thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchJobWithJob:) toTarget:self withObject:jobDescription];
```

If I do this that way, the class seems to get stuck on the connecting right away, with the only NSLog output being:

```
C: Attempting to connect to server at: mail.example.com:25
```

If I launch the job just by going `[self launchJobWithJob:jobDescription];`, it works fine but as I said before, lags heavily.

How can I get this to work in a background thread? Has someone come across this?

Edit: I have tried `NSOperationQueue` as well - the same happens again, just the log output and nothing else!

```
NSOperationQueue*queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation*operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(launchJobWithJob:) object:jobDescription];

[queue addOperation:operation];

[operation release];
```

Comment: have you tried using an NSOperation?

Comment: Yes I have - same problem. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that it does its network connection stuff on the runloop, so let the runloop of the thread run until the operation is finished.

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

Comment: it does it on the main thread, hence the freezing. Depending on the emails size, the user is at times unable to use the application efficiently - i do scale down images but it's much better to run this on a separate thread instead on the main() thread.

Comment: My answer referred to the [NSThread detachThreadSelector...] way, which you said you want. Or I don't understand your question

Comment: @David: I have the same problem now! When i do this: [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchJobWithJob:) toTarget:self withObject:jobDescription]; [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; it says that it has problems with the NSAutoreleasePool and still does nothing. How did you do that? Could you please show me a code sample also?

Comment: Please post this as a new question - this question is 2 years old soon.

Answer (score 0):

Must have some race condition, you can put some NSLog at you  launchJobWithJob method to detect which code cause problem.

Comment: if it would be this simple I'd jump out of joy :P