# SKPSMTPMessage freezing my program

Tags: ios, multithreading, email

Recently i decided to use the SKPSMTPMessage Class for transferring images to a server.

I subclassed the NSOperation Class, implemented the funktionality and added it to a NSOperationQueue, because i don't want my app to be blocked and the user can't do anything while its uploading the image. This usually occur, when i use the GSM network and it lasts a long time, until it the image is being sent. (By the way, i don't want to do any compressions on the image)

```
- (void)main {
SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

testMsg.fromEmail = [[_from copy] autorelease];
testMsg.toEmail = [[_to copy] autorelease];
testMsg.relayHost = [[_relayHost copy] autorelease];
testMsg.subject = [[_subject copy] autorelease];
testMsg.delegate = self.delegate;
testMsg.parts = [[_mailParts copy] autorelease];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[testMsg performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(send) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];}
```

To be clear, i release the obect in the delegate i assign to the SKPSMTMessage instance. So it's not causing any leaks.

The Problem is, that i have to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:` because otherwise its not working. It stops right after

> C: Attempting to connect to server at: mail.example.com:25

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482636/skpsmtpmessage-in-different-thread/4510146#comment12827001_4510146) post here, that describes pretty much the same problem i'm currently facing, but i can't figure out, how its going to work.

The solution they described was, that they used to run the program in another thread.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(launchJobWithJob:) toTarget:self withObject:jobDescription];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

But when i do this without using the NSOperation subclass, it causes me this error:

> _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x18a140 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

but still not working. It again only prints this "C: Attempting to connect to server at: mail.example.com:25".

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT**

In the Subclass NSOperation I now use instead of

```
[testMsg performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(send) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

that code.

```
[testMsg send];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

It helps me getting across the freezing problem, but the reliability of the message being sent is not given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now! I use following code in the NSOperation Subclass (btw: My subclasses name is SMTPSendOperation):

```
- (void)main
{

    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];

    testMsg.fromEmail = [[_from copy] autorelease];
    testMsg.toEmail = [[_to copy] autorelease];
    testMsg.relayHost = [[_relayHost copy] autorelease];
    testMsg.subject = [[_subject copy] autorelease];
    testMsg.delegate = self.delegate;
    testMsg.parts = [[_mailParts copy] autorelease];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    //[testMsg performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(send) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(send) toTarget:<#(id)#> withObject:<#(id)#>]

    [testMsg send];



    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

Anyhow, i'll have to tell the user to be patient until the mail is being sent successfully or failed. If anyone has any idea, how i can use the thread to be run more efficient, i'll really appreciate that!

Comment: I'm actually having an issue using SKPSMTPMessage. When in the process of sending the email, if the user pushes to a new controller, which I allow, the app crashes, until the second " *** stopping watchdog *** " log has been made.... I want to perform this on the main thread, freeze the UI so that the user cannot change views while the message is sent.... maybe this isn't the best Idea but I cant seem to get the crash to stop...

Comment: Hmmm .. weired. May i ask you, do you also pack the logic in a NSOperation and add it to a newly created NSOperationQueue? If so, does the operationqueue only exist in the pushed viewcontroller? Because this might be the problem. The operation needs to be canceled before the operationqueue is beeing released. I'd suggest (and i did this also), is to create a NSOperationQueue in the implementation of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. The viewcontroller only displays the data and creates a sendable object. This is my trick and i hope it helps you also!